# Pegar o índice de um valor em um array

Tags: c#, array

Como faço para pegar um índice de um valor do meu *array*? Por exemplo:

```
char[] letras = new char[]{'a','b','c','d'};
```

Em `letras`, eu gostaria de pegar o índice do valor `b` por exemplo. Como faço isso em C#?

Answer (score 8):

Se você ainda está a aprender, o código da resposta do leonardosnt é mais didáctico.

Se não use o método `IndexOf()` da classe Array.

```
char[] letras = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
int indice = Array.IndexOf(letras, 'c');
```

ou, simplificando:

```
char[] letras = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
var indice = Array.IndexOf(letras, 'c');
```

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar um loop para percorrer os itens do array até encontrar o desejado.

Por exemplo:

```
char[] letras = new char[]{'a','b','c','d'};

int indice = -1;

// Percorre todas as letras
for (int i = 0; i < letras.Length; i++) {
  // Verifica se a letra no índice 'i' é igual à letra c.
  if (letras[i] == 'c') {
    indice = i;
    break; // Para o loop
  }
}

// Se o indice for -1 aqui significa que o item que você está procurando não está no array.
```